# Codeigniter page URLs, page not found 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning the codeigniter using their General Topics Controller instructions. I have successfully installed codeigniter, but I can't seem to figure out the correct URL to go to the test file I created following their guide.

In the instructions it instructs me to create a file named blog.php and enter an echo statement and upload it to the controller directory.

Next it instructs me to view the file at www.domain.com/index.php/blog/, when I go there I get a Code igniter 404 error page.

Does anyone know a different URL I need to use?

Comment: Did you setup the route?

Comment: I used Softaculous on Cpanel to intall it, so I figured that would be setup. I did not see that in the Codeigniter install instructons either.

Comment: You don't install a route, you have to tell CI that you want to use a certain controller and method inside said controller to handle a given request. In your case, `/blog`

Comment: hi @MichaelFalciglia , just a suggestion you might want to read [Codeigniter URL](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) so you can understand more

Comment: Justin, I opened the routes.php file, and I noticed that welcome.php file that came with it had a route already and when I try to go to that file, I also get a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks Drixson, I am reading it over now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Softaculous installs CodeIgnitor on your server. But you need to configure routes for every MVC you build. Read the [routing guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) carefully or you can follow the [static page creation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the default welcome page that comes with the application still work even if I don't make any changes to the routing file?

Comment: It will work if you access the url `yourdomain.com`. Since `404` route is still intact, you are going to the error page.

Comment: What would the exact url to the welcome page be. I have tried these and have had all 404 errors
domain.com/index.php/welcome/
domain.com/index.php/welcome.html
domain.com/index.php/welcome.php
domain.com/welcome

Comment: by default, domain.com/index.php/welcome is the url. We can change this to other types by editing config files and .htaccess/webconfig files.

Comment: But it does not show up with that URL and I have not changed anything from the default installation and its giving me a 404 error, but the file is there.

Comment: I figured out the welcome issue from another forum, the welcome page does not work unless your files are in your root www folder. I had put codeigniter into a subfolder ci/